# passing a multidimentional array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define HODOR        long long int
#define INF          1234567890
#define rep(i, a, b) for(int i = (a); i < (b); ++i)
#define dwn(i, a, b) for(int i = (a); i >= (b); --i)
#define REP(c, it)   for( typeof( (c).begin()) it = (c).begin();  it !=  (c).end(); ++it)
#define DWN(c, it)   for( typeof( (c).end()) it = (c).end()-1;  it >= (c).begin(); --it)
#define ss(n)        scanf("%s",n)
#define FILL(x,y)    memset(x,y,sizeof(x))
#define pb           push_back
#define mp           make_pair
#define ALL(v)       v.begin(), v.end()
#define sz(a)        ((int)a.size())
#define SET(v, i)    (v | (1 << i))
#define TEST(v, i)   (v & (1 << i))
#define TOGGLE(v, i) (v ^ (1 << i))
#define gc           getchar
#define pc           putchar


template<typename X> inline void inp(X &n ) {
    register int ch=gc();int sign=1;n=0;
    while( ch < '0' || ch > '9' ){if(ch=='-')sign=-1; ch=gc();}
    while(  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' ) n = (n<<3)+(n<<1) + ch-'0', ch=gc();
    n=n*sign;
}

inline void inps(char *n) {
    register int ch=gc();
    int sign=1;
    int i=0;
    while( ch != '\n' ){ n[i]=(char)ch; ++i; ch=gc();}
    n[i]='\0';
}

int MaxPath(int arr[][100],int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int t,n;
    inp(t);

    while(t--) {
        inp(n);
        int arr[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                inp(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }

        float result = MaxPath(arr,n);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

> **Error seems like this :** error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[n]’ to ‘int (*)[100]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int MaxPath(int (*)[100], int)’

I have seen many posts on stckoverflow , but none of which seems to be working

Comment: I highly recommend you use your text editor's snippets feature instead of those macros. The bitwise ones could easily be functions instead of macros, or you could use `std::bitset`.

Comment: the code is well indented now

Comment: I think the arr[n][n] should be arr[][100]. The compiler must know the number of elements in a row for a 2D array. You can also use pointer to pointer in this specific case for passing the address of a 2D array.

Comment: could you could pass it as a pointer to a pointer to int `int** arr`

Comment: @bhzag i tried `int** arr`  error: cannot convert `int (*)[n]’ to ‘int**`

Comment: Consider discarding the 2d array in favour of a 1d array. Much easier to deal with and [often much, much faster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). Index with `arr[i*100+j]` instead of `arr[i][j]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in as a pointer to a pointer to int like this

```
 int MaxPath(int** arr,int n)
```

but for this to work you would have to declare int arr[n][n] differently

```
int main() {
    int t,n;
    inp(t);

    while(t--) {
        inp(n);
        int** arr = new int*[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                inp(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }

        float result = MaxPath(arr,n);
   }
   //deallocate arr
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       delete[] arr[i];
   }

   delete []arr;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to be able in MaxPath to calculate the address where the data item is stored. This is only possible if it knows the width of the matrix.

One of the simplest solutions is to create some kind of matrix class that implements a two- (or multi-) dimensional type on top of vector. It looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T> class matrix 
{
   std::vector<T> v;
   int width;
 public:
   matrix(int w, int h): v(w*h),width(w) {}
   T &operator()(int x, int y) { return v[x+y*width]; }
   const T &operator()(int x, int y) const { return v[x+y*width]; }

};


void f(matrix<int> &m) 
{
   printf("%d\n",m(1,2));
}

int main()
{
   matrix<int> m(5,5);

   m(1,2)=42;
   f(m);
}
```

This is just a minimal example and you may have to extend the matrix class for real world applications.